# how to split elements of a list into different sublists on occurence of a character

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I would like to split a list when a specific character occurs in the list.
for example

`lst=["abc","def","..","ghi","jkl",".."]`

to

`lst2=[["abc","def"],["ghi","jkl"]]`

so far I have tried using `itertools` and also `more_itertools` but to no avail.

Is there an efficient and easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: What was the problem with itertools? Looks like using `itertools.groupby` should have been a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @mkrieger1 points out, `itertools.groupby` should be your weapon of choice:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = ["abc", "def", "..", "ghi", "jkl", ".."]

print([list(group) for key, group in groupby(lst, key=lambda s: s != "..") if key])
```

Output:

```
[['abc', 'def'], ['ghi', 'jkl']]
>>>
```

Here's an explanation: `itertools.groupby` creates an iterator which yields tuples of keys and groups. a "key" in this context refers to some object that acts like a "group-category", and a "group" in this context is an iterator of consecutive elements that belong to the same group. By default, the key only compares items for equivalency - if they are the same, they belong in the same group. We can override this behavior with a custom key, which is a callable object (either a lambda, function, etc.) which takes an item as a parameter and returns a "group-category" object - something to signify a distinct group:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = ["abc", "def", "..", "ghi", "jkl", ".."]

def key(string):
    return string != ".."

for key, group in groupby(lst, key=key):
    print(key, list(group))
```

Output:

```
True ['abc', 'def']
False ['..']
True ['ghi', 'jkl']
False ['..']
>>>
```

In this case, our key is a boolean. Items are grouped according to the result of the callable `key`, which acts like a predicate. All adjacent objects for which the predicate was `True` are grouped together, and all adjacent objects for which the predicate was `False` are grouped together. Since we are only interested in those groups where the predicate was `True`, I used the optional filtering syntax in the list-comprehension to only retain those groups.

Comment: Thank you @Paul M. that worked like a charm can you explain it to me? Thanks again

Comment: @TheWitcher Sure, I've edited my post with an explanation.